# Does using a small part of a dependency make sense?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm using the Google Directions API to get a route between two points. Currently, I'm just sending an HTTP request to the API endpoint, like this:

```java
URL url;
URLConnection request;
    try {
        url = new URL(
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json" +
            "?origin=Alzenau" +
            "&destination=Dortmund&" +
            "key=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        );

        request = url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();

        ConvertRoutes(rootobj);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, there is a Google dependency I can use to achieve the same thing: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps/google-maps-services/0.9.3

This dependency contains all the Google Maps API's (Directions, Places etc.)

My question: Does it make sense to use the dependency from Google when I'm only using a small fraction of its features? Does Java load the whole dependency, or only the pieces I actually use?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just load the dependency that you're actually using and then exclude all the transitive dependencies, which might not be used by you, but by other features of the api (which you still don't use)

Comment: That depends on how the library is built but it might load more classes than needed. Would that really be a problem though? Are you memory bound?

Comment: @Lino The Google Dependency includes all of it's API's in one dependencies as far as I know, so i couldn't exclude one since they all reside in the same artifact

Comment: @Thomas It is no problem at all to use the library, I'm just wondering what I should be considering "best practise"

Comment: I suggest you should use your own code. This will give you more control on sending the request such as adding timeouts.

Comment: @Lino I would be careful in excluding transitive dependencies because it is difficult to check whether these dependencies are somehow used in some call stack.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon to include a dependency for a single class. Many projects now try to be modular so you aren't including a *massive* amount of unused code, but "all of Google Maps" doesn't seem to be an overly large dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a clear yes/no decision.

If you just call the one http interface and your application runs fine (and is fast enough), there is no real reason to change it.

Using the Java API will probably make your code smaller (and you have type safety), but you need to check the dependency tree of that API. If it contains dependencies you already have in your dependency tree, you might get conflicts due to different versions of the same artifacts.

Comment: Would I use the library, I'd have 2 different versions of the Apache httpclient dependency. Good thing to consider, thanks for your answer!